# Looping through images once and getting mouse coordinates of each mouse click

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following script. I need to get the coordinates of each mouse click coordinates sent to my email at the end of the loop of the images. Can someone please help me with this?
I am very new in this, and am trying to implement some of my memory tasks for online. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

here's my script:

```
<head>
    <title>Practice2</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="MemStyle.CSS">
    <script type = "text/javascript">        
       var x=0;
       function changeImage() 
       {
if (x == images.length){
return;      
}

          document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]
          x++;
       }


      var images =  ["S2b.jpg", "S3b.jpg", "S4b.jpg", "S5b.jpg", "S1b.jpg"];       

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MemImg">
       <button onclick="changeImage()" >
           <img id="img"  width="700px" height="700px" >
       </button>   
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not declare your array like: `[ "S2b.jpg", "...", ... ]`? You are missing `images[0]` because arrays are 0-indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = 1;
function changeImage() 
{
    if (x > images.length)
    {
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
    x++;
}
```

BTW, @tadman's suggestion is good:

```
var images = ["S2b.jpg", "S3b.jpg", "S4b.jpg", "S5b.jpg", "S1b.jpg"];
```

Then change your `x` declaration to:

```
var x = 0;
```

And the condition:

```
if (x == images.length)
```

As @Shaiful Islam suggested, you can reset the counter by changing the `return;` to `x = 0`.

Comment: If you want loop through the image then reset the value of x when it reach to images length

Comment: @ShaifulIslam I can't think for the OP. He didn't describes it, further he could do it by himself, it not that hard, I'm afraid.

Comment: I just suggested it for him.

Comment: I am new in this so help is very appreciated! I also have more questions that i will post below

Comment: I have changed/updated my questions, can you please help me with this question? @ShaifulIslam a

Comment: I have changed/updated my questions, would you be able to help me with that please? @ShaifulIslam

Comment: @nahidz for new question you have to create a new post, I'm afraid.